# No puedo conectar la base de datos

Tags: php

No me insertan los datos, cuando quito la linea de *error_reporting(0)* me aparece lo siguiente **NOTICE: UNDEFINED INDEX**

```js
// AQUÍ AL INTENTAR INSERTAR DATOS ME APARECE NOTICE: UNDEFINED INDEX CUANDO BORRO EL ERROR REPORTING
<?php

include("conexion.php");

$number = $_POST['number'];
$identification = $_POST['identification'];

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    
    $conexion->query("INSERT INTO $database_user (number,identification) VALUES ('$number','$identification')");
    
}


?>


// ASÍ ES COMO ESTOY CONECTANDO LA BASE DE DATOS


<?php 

$host = "localhost";
$user = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";

$database_users = "users"; // USERS
$database_numbers = "numbers"; // NUMBERS

error_reporting(0); // NO REPORTING

$conexion = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database);

if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    echo "No es posible conectarte";
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: Coloca el mensaje de error completo por favor

Answer (score 0):

El error que describes ocurre cuando haces referencia por ejemplo a una posición dentro de un array que no existe.

por ejemplo:

```
$array = ['a','b','c'];
echo $array[7];
```

Tendrá el mismo error porque no existe la posición `7` en el array (sino solo 0, 1 y 2).

Del mismo modo:

```
$array = array(
    'primero': 1,
    'segundo': 2 
);
echo $array['tercero'];
```

Tendrá el mismo problema para el caso de `Indexed Arrays`.

Sin tener mayor información que lo que comentas, me parece que tienes que revisar las líneas:

```
$number = $_POST['number'];
$identification = $_POST['identification'];
```

primero porque deberías chquear si están seteadas (si no se envía el formulario esas variables no existen):

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['identification'])) {

    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $identification = $_POST['identification'];    

    $conexion->query("INSERT INTO {$database_users} (number,identification) VALUES ('{$number}','{$identification}')");

}
?>
```

y también porque en `conexion.php` tienes una variable `$database_users` y en la query estás referenciando a `$database_user` (falta la 's' al final).

Igualmente te sugiero con énfasis en que leas documentación sobre cómo prevenir `injection attacks` porque así tal cual, está vulnerable a que el usuario pueda insertar código en el formulario que puedan por ejemplo exponer datos que no quieres exponer.

Como último dato, no olvides chequear que los `input names` en el formulario `html` sean correctos.